# sympy: given symbols u, v, w how do I tell it that u*u + v*v + w*w is 1?

Tags: sympy

I have a 3D unit vector with components `(v1, v2, v3)`.

I do some manipulation and arrive at this matrix (its a 2x2 matrix in case you don't get it):

```
>>> Q
⎡              ⎛        _________________⎞                            ⎛        _________________⎞            ⎤
⎢              ⎜       ╱   2     2     2 ⎟                            ⎜       ╱   2     2     2 ⎟            ⎥
⎢            ⅈ⋅⎝v₃ - ╲╱  v₁  + v₂  + v₃  ⎠                          ⅈ⋅⎝v₃ + ╲╱  v₁  + v₂  + v₃  ⎠            ⎥
⎢─────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────⎥
⎢                   __________________________________                     __________________________________⎥
⎢                  ╱                            2                         ╱                            2     ⎥
⎢                 ╱  │        _________________│                         ╱  │        _________________│      ⎥
⎢                ╱   │       ╱   2     2     2 │                        ╱   │       ╱   2     2     2 │      ⎥
⎢               ╱    │v₃ - ╲╱  v₁  + v₂  + v₃  │                       ╱    │v₃ + ╲╱  v₁  + v₂  + v₃  │      ⎥
⎢(ⅈ⋅v₁ - v₂)⋅  ╱     │─────────────────────────│  + 1   (ⅈ⋅v₁ - v₂)⋅  ╱     │─────────────────────────│  + 1 ⎥
⎢            ╲╱      │        ⅈ⋅v₁ - v₂        │                    ╲╱      │        ⅈ⋅v₁ - v₂        │      ⎥
⎢                                                                                                            ⎥
⎢                          1                                                      1                          ⎥
⎢      ─────────────────────────────────────────              ─────────────────────────────────────────      ⎥
⎢             __________________________________                     __________________________________      ⎥
⎢            ╱                            2                         ╱                            2           ⎥
⎢           ╱  │        _________________│                         ╱  │        _________________│            ⎥
⎢          ╱   │       ╱   2     2     2 │                        ╱   │       ╱   2     2     2 │            ⎥
⎢         ╱    │v₃ - ╲╱  v₁  + v₂  + v₃  │                       ╱    │v₃ + ╲╱  v₁  + v₂  + v₃  │            ⎥
⎢        ╱     │─────────────────────────│  + 1                 ╱     │─────────────────────────│  + 1       ⎥
⎣      ╲╱      │        ⅈ⋅v₁ - v₂        │                    ╲╱      │        ⅈ⋅v₁ - v₂        │            ⎦
```

How do I tell sympy that since I am dealing with a unit vector `v1*v1 + v2*v2 + v3*v3` is equal to `1` and have it simplify the result for me?

Comment: Have you tried `Q.subs(v1*v1 + v2*v2 + v3*v3, 1)`?

Comment: it works. can you post it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple cases like this you can use `Q.subs(v1*v1 + v2*v2 + v3*v3, 1)`.